# batch files process in bash to change proper output name

Tags: bash

I want to execute bunch of job using bash.

I whote a script below.

```
for fname in data/*/*.pcm
do
    FrontEnd "$fname" "`dirname $fname`/`basename $fname`.mfc"
done
```

But  output file is like aaa.pcm.mfc when original is aaa.pcm.

I want to make output aaa.mfc.

Where should I fix this code?

Comment: It occurs to me this should maybe be on SuperUser, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on `Manipulating Strings` (http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for fname in data/*/*.pcm
do
    FrontEnd "$fname" "${fname%.*}.mfc"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, using the suffix option of the `basename` command should be handy, i.e. `.pcm`.

```
for fname in data/*/*.pcm
do
    FrontEnd "$fname" "`dirname $fname`/`basename $fname .pcm`.mfc"
done
```

Comment: Though you might as well say `"${fname%.pcm}.mfc"`.